# Can I safely affix tile to a panel of plywood?

Tags: tile, plywood

I plan on affixing some 5/8" glass mosaic tile to a panel of plywood roughly 43 x 44". I then plan on using that as the face of our bar by affixing that plywood to the bar.

My concern is that they thinset might not work very well on the plywood. I was told that if I wet the plywood first before laying the thinset mortar, it shouldn't be a problem. Does anybody have any experience doing this or maybe have some suggestions on how to make this project a success?

Also, what would be the best thickness for the thinset in order to lay the tile properly?

Answer (score 2):

I would use an external grade ply, seal underside and edges with acrylic primer
and stick the tiles with an adhesive suitable for glass mosaic.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so, you are suggesting getting rid of the thinset mortar altogether?